# Проблема с khrplatform.h при подключении GLAD

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Ошибка:
[image: Ошибка:]

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта:]

```
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include "glfw3.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{

}
```

При подключении GLAD компилятор не может найти khrplatform.h. Пробовал указывать с помощью -L, -I, -l но как-то не помогло.

Компилирую через g++ D:\gamedev\cpp-workspace\Lesson_1\main.cpp -o out

Comment: Попробуйте директорию KHR засунуть в директорию glad

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: В таком случае приведите возникающую ошибку. Энивей, надо описать в вопросе как именно вы собираете ваш проект, используете ли `make/cmake`, если нет, то просто флаги сборки укажите. Всё это в вопрос, а не в комментарии, с помощью кнопки править

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что ответ запоздал, но его можно просто запихнуть в папку /usr/include командной ***sudo cp -R KHR /usr/include***, но я сюда зашел, чтобы увидеть решение другой проблемы, а именно дублирование функций из glad.h.

Comment: вот не делайте так никогда. Можно сильно испортить себе жизнь, если начинающий разработчик. Скопируйте нужные файлы в отдельную папку и добавьте ее в опции компиляции через `-I` (больша i) (это для gcc/clang).

Comment: О опять ты :) Может ты знаешь как библотеку Glad в проекте подключить? У меня проблема дублирования происходит, пишет что функции (выдается их список) переподключены.